# Flask - contact form sending email on submit, but not redirecting and bootstrap btn not showing

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image]

```
from flask_mail import Mail, Message

app.config['MAIL_SERVER'] = 'xxxx'
app.config['MAIL_PORT'] = 465
app.config['MAIL_USERNAME'] = 'xxxx'
app.config['MAIL_PASSWORD'] = 'xxxx'
app.config['MAIL_USE_TLS'] = False
app.config['MAIL_USE_SSL'] = True
app.config['MAIL_DEFAULT_SENDER'] = 'xxx'
mail = Mail(app)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'xxx'

# Contact Form
class ContactForm(FlaskForm):
    name =StringField("Name",validators=[DataRequired()])
    email = StringField("Email",validators=[DataRequired(), Email()])
    message = TextAreaField("Message",validators=[DataRequired()])
    submit = SubmitField('Send')

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def home():
    form = ContactForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit() == False:
        return render_template('home2.html',form=form)
    else:
        msg = Message('WEBSITE CONTACT', sender='xxx', recipients=['xxxx'])
        msg.body = '%s \n %s \n\n %s ' % (form.name.data, form.email.data, form.message.data)
        mail.send(msg)
        return redirect(url_for('form_complete'))
    return render_template('home2.html',form=form)

@app.route('/complete')
def form_complete():
    return render_template('form_submitted.html')
```

The contact form successfully sends the email, however it does not redirect to form_complete.

I would like, after the contact form has been submitted (via a bootstrap button), for an email to be sent and a redirect to form_submitted.html

Furthermore, if I change the class in the HTML, the `Send` text just disappears:

```
...
<div class="container">
        <h3 class="big text-center" data-aos="fade-down" data-aos-delay="0">
            Contact
        </h3>
        <form method="POST" action ="">
            {{ form.hidden_tag() }}

            {% for message in form.name.errors %}
              <div class="flash"><br><br>{{ message }}<br><br></div>
            {% endfor %}

            {{ form.name.label(class="form-control-label") }}
            {{ form.name(class="form-control form-control-lg") }}


            {% for message in form.email.errors %}
            <div class="flash"><br><br>{{ message }}<br><br></div>
            {% endfor %}

            {{ form.email.label(class="form-control-label") }}
            {{ form.email(class="form-control form-control-lg") }}

            {% for message in form.message.errors %}
            <div class="flash"><br><br>{{ message }}<br><br></div>
            {% endfor %}

            {{ form.message.label(class="form-control-label") }}
            {{ form.message(class="form-control form-control-lg") }}

            <!--{# {{ form.submit(class="btn btn-outline-info") }} #}-->
            {{ form.submit() }}
        </form>
    </div>
...
```

edit:
When the submit button is pressed the contact form correctly sends to my email, though it doesn't redirect as I would like.

There is a script.js containing some remnant php form info - but removing this from script.js has not changed anything.

**Github:**
https://github.com/olbliss/OB_Flask

Comment: what happens when you submit form does it remain on the same page?

Comment: can you show us the structure of the directory did you save HTML files on the templates directory, or what happens after you click submit button because I tested everything on my local machines and it works perfectly without any errors.

Comment: @GiorgiImerlishvili all the HTML files are saved to the templates directory. When the submit button is pressed the contact form correctly sends to my email, though it doesn't redirect as I would like. There is a script.js containing some remnant php form info - but remvoing this from script.js has not changed anything

Comment: @Chandan yes when submit button is pressed, it remains on the same page - though it does send the mail correctly.

Comment: @ob318 Can you share us whole Project? it will be easier for us to debug and help you.

Comment: @GiorgiImerlishvili can do indeed. Apologies. What is the best way to do this? e.g. the script.js is ~350 lines long, but I'm fairly confident that this isn't where the issue lies. What is the best way for my to share this?

Comment: @ob318 just share your code using `github`

Comment: @DanilaGanchar Github link added to the question

Comment: @GiorgiImerlishvili Github link added to the question

Comment: @ob318 I will check it.

Answer (score 2):

I found the issue, It was Caused By `script.js`. 
in `static/script.js` Comment Out or just delete The Line 170

```
$("form:not(.SFG)").submit(function(event){

        // event.preventDefault();

        var form = $(this);
        var grecaptchaContainer = document.getElementById("g-recaptcha");
        if($(grecaptchaContainer).length>0){
```

Comment Out or just delete `event.preventDefault();` and everything will work.

In Bootstrap Button, you have naming Conflincts between Bootstrap.css and `framework.css` and `framework.min.css` Because there are Class`.btn` which affects Bootstrap class `.btn` that's why your Bootstrap Button Doesn't appear You need to change naming of that `.btn` class in `static\framework.css` and `static\framework.min.css`

Comment: Thank you, yes that seems to be working now. Do you have a solution to the second part of my question - the bootstrap btn not showing.

Comment: @ob318 Submit Button?

Comment: Thanks. I can see that .btn is found in framwork.css from line 159. That's why I am confused as to why it doesn't actually work, what would I rename it to adn where would I call this new name in order for it to change?

Comment: you can rename it as for example `btn-fr` and also change it as `btn-fr` everywhere where you used it.

Comment: I have changed all `.btn` to `.btn_new` in `framework.css` and `framework.min.css` and also changed it in `home2.html` - the button simply doesn't show.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233843/discussion-between-giorgi-imerlishvili-and-ob318).

Comment: can you reply to the chat please

Comment: if you wanted to continue this discussion in chat, at least reply to it please